# Using grep how to search some string and exclude some string in same record

Tags: linux, grep

```
test1 |test2 |abc@gmail.com |sucess

test1 |test2 |cde@gmail.com |success

test1 |test2 |success.12@gmail.com |failure

test1 |test2 |SUCCESS12@gmail.com |failure
```

Output:

```
zgrep 'test1.*success\|success.*test1' test.txt 

test1 |test2 |abc@gmail.com |success

test1 |test2 |cde@gmail.com |success

test1 |test2 |success.12@gmail.com |failure
```

How to avoid showing up 3rd record in output?

Comment: Does `zgrep 'test1.*success\|success.*test1' test.txt | grep -v failure` do what you want?

Comment: Thanks john for your reply.  I used this one and it worked. grep 'test1.*success\|success.*test1' test.txt | zgrep -iv '.*success.*@.*'. I added regex so that if any recored is there like 'test1 |test2 |success.12@gmail.com |success'  then this will not get pulled

Answer (score 0):

The following does the job:

```
grep 'test1.*|.*|.*|success' test.txt
```

This works, as long as the delimiter '|' does not occur in the fields in between.